# Argue on elementary grounds that the average value of $x/y$ exceeds 1 if x and y are chosen randomly between 1 and 2

Tags: calculus, average

**Textbook problem:**

> Two numbers, first $x$ and then $y$, are chosen at random between $1$ and $2$. What is the average value of the quotient $\frac{x}{y}$? Can you argue on elementary grounds that the answer must exceed 1?

**My answer:** If $x$ has been picked, then the average of the quotient is
$$
\int_1^2 \frac{x}{y}\,dy = x\ln(2)
$$
Averaging over possible values of $x$ yields
$$
\int_1^2 x\ln(2)\, dx = \frac{3}{2}\ln(2) \approx 1.03
$$
But this is not an argument based on elementary grounds I don't think.

Interpreting the average value of a function over an interval as being the height of the rectangle with base on the interval and with the same area as the area under the function over the interval leads me to the following argument.

The average value of $x$ is $3/2$. The quotient $x/y$ then ranges from $3/4$ to $3/2$. We can underestimate the area under this curve by splitting it up into a rectangle with length $1$ and height $3/4$ and a right triangle on top of the rectangle whose hypotenuse is the tangent line to the curve $\frac{3}{2y}$ at the point $(3/2,1)$. This gives a triangle with height $7/12$ and base $7/8$.

So an underestimate for the area under the curve would be $\left(1\cdot \frac{3}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{7}{8}\cdot \frac{7}{12}\right) = \frac{193}{192}$.

Here is an illustration of my quotient function with $x = 3/2$, the tangent line, and the rectangle:
[image: quotient]

Since the base of the rectangle with the same area on $[1,2]$ has length $1$ its height must be at least $\frac{193}{192}$ to match the area under the graph.  Hence, the height, or average value, exceeds $1$.

**Question:** Does this seem to be an argument the author could be looking for instead of integrating?

This is a single variable calculus text.  The section is ''The Average Value of a Function". Note that not until the next chapter is probability introduced.

**Update:** I have obtained a copy of the author's own solutions manual. Here is the official solution:

> To argue on elementary grounds that the answer must exceed 1, note that the outcomes $a/b$ and $b/a$ must occur equally often, so that the answer is certainly greater than the *minimum* over all $a$ and $b$ in $[1,2]$ of the average of these two numbers. Now this average is
> $$
> \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{a}\right] = \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2ab}
> $$
> and this is always greater than 1 because $a^2 + b^2 - 2ab = (a-b)^2 > 0$.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the name of this textbook?

Comment: "Calculus: The Analysis of Functions" by Peter D. Taylor. @BrianTung

Comment: Is there something missing from the problem statement at the start of the main body of your post? It seems like you need the reference to the ratio $x/y$, which currently only occurs in your title. Generally speaking, we prefer that no content occur solely in the title. Sorry, I know it's a little nitpicky, but it does help! (On a side note, I came up with an answer that is about as elementary as I can make it. No calculus.)

Comment: @BrianTung  Good catch! I missed a sentence, and have now added it.

Comment: Good! Hopefully this resolves any confusion about whether the average or the median value is meant.

Comment: Neat question, by the way. I assume there's no solution given?

Comment: @BrianTung No. It's what brings me here.

Comment: Your missing statement made me comment on every answer to Point out that there some Interpretation Issue. Of course, this mass commenting made some folks (including me) unhappy ! ok , I am going to delete my answer which was based on Interpretation when Problem Statement was incomplete !

Comment: @Prem: It didn't make me unhappy, but in my opinion, if you think there's an alternate interpretation that everyone else is missing, the best thing is to appeal to the OP to clarify, rather than pre-emptively insisting that everyone else is interpreting the question incorrectly.

Comment: Well, I saw only 1 Possible Interpretation when I answered. Hence I was commenting based on that. Later I realized that the title was not matching. That was when I commented to check the Content rather than title, hoping that OP will clarify !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can argue as follows. The probability distribution is symmetric w.r.t. interchanging $x$ and $y$. This means that we can compute the expectation value by restricting $x$ to be larger than or equal to $y$ and computing the expectation value of $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}\right)$ over this modified probability distribution.

The fact that the expectation value exceeds $1$ then follows from the fact that the function $f(x,y)$ is larger than or equal to $1$:

$$f(x,y) - 1 = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x}-2\right) = \frac{x^2+y^2-2xy}{2xy} = \frac{(x-y)^2}{2 xy}\geq 0$$

The function $f(x,y)$ is then equal to $1$ when $x = y$ which occurs on a subset of measure zero, so the expectation value is clearly larger than $1$.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest argument. Algebraically, in one line: since $\mathbb E[\frac xy]=\mathbb E[\frac yx]$, we have $$\mathbb E\left[\frac xy\right]=\frac{\mathbb E[\frac xy]+\mathbb E[\frac yx]}2=\mathbb E\left[\frac{x/y+y/x}2\right]=\mathbb E\left[1+\frac{(x-y)^2}{2xy}\right]=1+\mathbb E\left[\frac{(x-y)^2}{2xy}\right]>1.$$

Comment: @Prem: Again, you're determining that the *median* value is $1$. The *average* value is somewhat in excess of $1$. (In this context, "expected value" means the same thing as "average value," with respect to the uniform distribution.)

Comment: This is the way I am reading it [[ Textbook problem: Two numbers, first x and then y, are chosen at random between 1 and 2. Can you argue on elementary grounds that the answer **(x/y)** must exceed 1? ]] I think this means x exceeds y. Which is as likely as y exceeds x, which means 50-50

Comment: If Content is updated to match the Title, my answer will become wrong & I will delete it. If title is updated to match Problem Statement & my assumption, then answer will be 50-50.

Comment: @Prem: OP has edited the post; please re-examine, thanks!

Comment: @MishaLavrov My problem here is that this problem is supposed to be done without any knowledge or use of probability distributions or properties of expected value.  Nevertheless, I follow completely.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in fact $\frac{3}{2} \log 2$, as correctly stated in the question.

The flaw in the geometric argument is that the average being taken is an *arithmetic* mean, not a geometric mean.  To illustrate, suppose that instead of $X$ and $Y$ being chosen on $[1,2]$, consider instead the discrete case where $X, Y \in \{1, 2\}$.  Then we have for instance $\Pr[X/Y = 2] = \Pr[X/Y = 1/2]$ but the *expectation* is $\frac{\frac{1}{2} + 2}{2} > 1$.

This reasoning suggests that a modification to the geometric argument will suffice in proving the expectation exceeds $1$.  All that is needed is an application of the AM-GM inequality and a limiting argument.

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly discrete uniform on the set $$\left\{1 + \frac{k}{n}\right\}_{k = 1}^n.$$  Then the above argument shows that the conditional expectation of $Z = X/Y$ given $Z \in \{z, 1/z\}$ is $$\frac{z + 1/z}{2} \ge \sqrt{z \cdot 1/z} = 1.$$  Then take again the expectation over all such $z$ in the support, and we see that the total expectation must exceed $1$.  Then in the limit as $n \to \infty$, $X$ and $Y$ become continuous uniform on $[1,2]$ and we are done.

A less formal way to reason, then, is to observe that for any point in the square $[1,2] \times [1,2]$, there is a matching point whose slope is the reciprocal; their average slope, by the AM-GM inequality, must exceed $1$, so the average taken over all such points in the square will also exceed $1$.

Comment: Can you pinpoint the error in my geometric argument as in which sentence?  The average value is indeed the height of the rectangle with the same area.  I don't know any probability or that inequality; this is first-semester calculus.

Comment: @UngarLinski I'm not referring to your geometric argument:  I'm referring to the other answer by Prem.

Comment: As for your specific argument, you cannot compute the average of $X/Y$ by only considering its values when $X$ is at its average.

Comment: Why not exactly? I can't justify it myself but I also can't not justify it.  But you are right: my argument hinges on that.  Maybe the answer the author was looking for is that it 'can't' be argued on elementary grounds. I mean isn't the AM-GM inequality you mention nonelementary?

Comment: @UngarLinski: I'd consider AM-GM elementary, myself.

Comment: @heropup Me finding the average of $x$ first (3/2) and then estimating the area under the curve $\frac{3/2}{y}$ with the rectangle and triangle on top is me estimating $\int_1^2 \frac{\int_1^2 x\, dx}{y}\,dy$.  And this integral actually gives the exact answer. So what is my error when finding the average of $x$ first?

Answer (score 2):

A calculus-free approach:

Consider the sequence $p_n, n > 0$ given by $p_n = \frac{2n}{n+1}$. Draw line segments from the origin to the points $(p_n, 2)$, and to the points $(2, p_n)$. Where these segments cross the square, they divide it into wedges. Call the wedges in the upper half of the square $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$, starting from the upper left corner, and call the wedges in the lower half of the square $B_1, B_2, B_3, \ldots$, starting from the lower right corner.

[image]

Notice that the ratio $x/y$ increases monotonically as we proceed from left to right. Now, let $a_n$ be the average value of the ratio $x/y$ in the wedge $A_n$, and similarly let $b_n$ be the average value of the ratio $x/y$ in the wedge $B_n$. Because $x/y$ increases from left to right, we have that $a_n > \frac{p_n}{2} = \frac{n}{n+1}$ and $b_n > \frac{2}{p_{n+1}} = \frac{n+2}{n+1}$. Since $A_n$ and $B_n$ have equal areas, the average of the ratio $x/y$ across both areas is $\frac{a_n+b_n}{2} > 1$.

Finally, since the wedges $A_n$ and $B_n$ collectively cover the entire square, the average of the ratio $x/y$ over the entire square is greater than $1$.